# why foreach print just one value in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, laravel-5

I have a method:

```
public function winnerDetails()
{     
    $winners = DB::table('winners')->get();   
    //dd($winners);
    foreach ($winners as $winner) {
        $qrMainId = $winner->qrdetails_id;
    }
   dd($qrMainId);
}
```

`dd($winners);` returns to value of `array` but when i use `foreach` its returns one value. How can i get who value returns with `foreach` loop?

`dd($winners)` output:

[image]

and `dd($qrMainId);` return one value `44`. But it should return another value of array `35`; Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are overwritting the value of `$qrMainId` on each `foreach()` loop. If you want all values, you need to save the values to an array or concatenate the string value.

Answer (score 1):

To get array of ID's use

```
   foreach ($winners as $winner) {
    $qrMainId[]= $winner->qrdetails_id;
```

For just value use

```
   $qrMainId='';
   foreach ($winners as $winner) {
    $qrMainId.= $winner->qrdetails_id;
```

Comment: I want just value not an array. It will return array.

Comment: Its return undefined  `$qrMainId` when i print as `dd($qrMainId);`

Comment: Nope its returns array. i want just value like this: https://prnt.sc/gx4exu

Comment: What is the return of $winner->qrdetails_id

Comment: I think this answer is missing the whole point of use Laravel

Comment: No it is not laravel is a framework for Php sometimes adding [] to represent array or (.) For concatenation is more simple thing to search for framework way to do it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to accomplish this task in a Laravel way use the pluck method to map the array for the key that you want

```
 <?php
public function winnerDetails()
{     
    $winnersId = DB::table('winners')->get()->pluck('qrdetails_id');   
   dd($winnersId);
}
```

Comment: I know but it will return as array. But i want the collection of values.

Comment: Do you mean a Laravel Collection?

Comment: Actually the pluck method returns a Collection

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not leveraging the power of Laravel here. Obviously, I don't know what you are trying to do but here are some pointers.

You should probably be making a [model](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent) for the winners table now models in Laravel return Collections as does the DB facade you are using now. Now the Collection class contains alot of usefull helpers like [pluck](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-pluck)

At this point it becomes as easy as `Winner::all()->pluck('id')` and you got yourself an array of id's.

And if you would like to get them comma seperated or anything like that you can use the [implode](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-implode)

And you would get `Winner::all()->implode('id',',');`

Answer (score 0):

$qrMainId is a variable not an array.

It is modified in the foreach during every loop.

So your code has always the last element of the array.

Use an array to collect values like

```
$qrMainId[] = $winner->qrdetails_id;
```

or sql select directly the field you want.